# WCF Proxy Returning Array instead of List EVEN THOUGH Collection Type == Generic.List

Tags: wcf, tfs, visual-studio-2012, wcf-client

I have a VS 2010 solution containing a WCF Library project and another project consuming that web service.  After opening in VS 2012, it was upgraded.

The proxy now returns List<T> types as arrays, even though CollectionMappings is clearly set to Generic.List.

What could be happening?

Someone else has a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298066/wcf-returning-array-instead-of-list-even-though-collection-type-generic-list) but he was downgrading from VS 2012 to VS 2010 instead.

Edit: I double checked, and Reference.svcmap contains:

```
<CollectionMappings>
  <CollectionMapping TypeName="System.Collections.Generic.List`1" Category="List" />
</CollectionMappings>
```

but Reference.cs contains stuff such as:

```
 public xxx.ServiceReference1.ADUser[] get_ADUsers;
```

when in the web service it is:

```
 public List<ADUser> get_ADUsers(string wildcard, string sortexp, string sortorder)
```

More info (added Dec 12, 2012):

The solution, created in VS2010, was working fine on another PC.  It was checked into TFS from that PC.  On this problematic PC, we did a mapping and GET.  When we try to build, we got that error where all the List<T> types used in the service reference were all somehow treated as arrays.  We installed VS 2010 on the problematic PC and GET that solution too.  And the same error is also there.  So, it appears it is not related to VS 2012.

All PCs are Windows 7 Professional.

More info (added Dec 19, 2012):

When the project was opened, ServiceReferences/ServiceReference1/Reference.cs on the local PC was modified automatically.  The changes were huge.  Below is a small part of it:

[image]

Two methods are shown.  List<string> get_Hotlines() become string[] get_Hotlines() and List<string> get_HotlinesBySite() becomes string[] get_HotlinesBySite().

Why is the file changed even without my asking?  The VS 2012 upgrade log said two files were changed but Reference.cs wasn't one of them.

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. Did you try to regenerate the proxy with appropriate collection mapping?

Comment: Yes, I have regenerated the proxy many times.  I even duplicate it by adding a second one with a different name (ServiceReference2) to the same service.  The problem is the same.  Under Advanced, Collection type is set to System.Collections.Generic.List.  Another PC next to it has the exact same settings but it works.

Comment: Are you sure it still uses the DataContractSerializer? (E.g. do generated classes have the [DataContract] attribute?) Perhaps it switched to XmlSerializer for some reason, which doesn't honor the collection mapping settings.

Comment: To be clear, you are right-clicking on you client project and choosing "Add service reference", and setting the Collection Type to System.Collections.Generic.List in the advanced options, correct? Have you tried to generate a proxy with svcutil.exe? Additionally, is the "PC next to yours" adding the same reference for the same WCF project you are? With the same configuration?

Comment: @Gabe Thorns: yes, I did it as you described. No, I did not try with svcutil.  This is a controlled project in TFS.  If I add the service reference differently, then everyone else is affected.  As I said, another PC is working fine.  It's only this new PC that has a problem.  I checked out, did not modify any file, and tried to compile.

Comment: @EugeneOsovetsky, another PC created the project according to Microsoft text book instructions on how to create and consume a WCF in Visual Studio, it worked perfectly, and checked in to TFS.  This PC checked it out, and did not modify any file.  When trying to compile, all the client methods bombed because they were expecting List<T> but the proxy returned arrays.

Comment: Still, could you check which serializer the proxy uses, DataContractSerializer or XmlSerializer?

Comment: Sorry, could you help with how to check.  So far, we have been doing everything automated via Visual Studio.  Thanks.

Comment: List<Type> and Type[] are basically serialized the same way (XML) in SOAP, it's your client code that determines how to handle the collection. This is for decoupling and giving WCF enough flexibility to be consumed by not .NET clients. That means your proxy is not being generated correctly (could it be that your project settings are not pointing to the correct version of the framework you're using?). Take a look at your proxy (code generated by Add Service Reference or svcutil) and make sure it's handling your collections as List<> instead of Type[].

Comment: I did it all over again.  The moment I GET the project from TFS, ServiceReferences/ServiceRefernce1/Reference.cs is modified, even thought I did not do anything to change it.  I compared the local file with the server's version, and there were many changes.  I include a screenshot in my original post.

Comment: Correction. Reference.cs was created only when the solution was opened. VS 2012 then "upgraded" the project, and it reports non-functional changes in two files, the sln file and the consumption project file csproj.  And somewhere at this point Reference.cs got changed.

Comment: OK, it looks like the change in Reference.cs occurs when I Update the Service Reference.  Even though the setting for Collection type is at System.Collections.Generic.List, when the reference is updated, it Downloads Service Information..., and at that point Reference.cs gets changed into one where all the return types are  arrays.

Comment: Do you have all Service Packs for .NET and Visual Studio installed?

Comment: So I know this is an old question, but this is something that I also encountered. It seems that when svcutil.exe encounters something that it does not know how to serialize all bets are off. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657982/wcf-returns-arrayofkeyvalueofintstringkeyvalueofintstring-instead-of-dictionar/16673773#16673773

Comment: Did you every find a solution to this problem? I have a solution with two projects. Both projects consume the same service, so have the same svcmap. One project generates lists, the other one arrays.

Answer (score 4):

When you add reference to wcf service you need to change Collection Type to Generic List:

[image]

You can also update this settings just select service reference inside your solution, make right mouse click and select "Configure Service Reference..."

Comment: Yes, this is what I have done all the time.  As I explained, despite this setting at System.Collections.Gernic.List, the methods generated by the proxy are all arrays as seen in Reference.cs.  When the project was first opened on this PC, Reference.cs was created and it contained List<T> methods.  But whenever I Update the Service Reference, all the List<T> methods become array methods.

Comment: There are two options you can take, since tfs is involved. First option would be to remove complete wcf service reference and add it again with correct List collection type. Second, go to file system where reference files are placed, select all the files and remove read only flag for all reference files and then update the reference inside VS again. Issue is with the tfs.

Comment: -1 The OP stated that he had already done this.  I am also seeing the same problem.  It generates Lists on a coworker's machine, and Arrays on mine, even though we have the same setting in the Service Reference Settings dialog.

Answer (score 0):

What did it for me was:

1. install all updates to Visual Studio 2013
2. uncheck "reuse types in referenced assemblies"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with VS2010. After hours of trying and testing I think, this is a bug of code generation. I was able to reproduce it. Here is code on server side, which has impact on behavior of Visual Studio code generation. 
The commented line generated this problem in my case. When this member was not nullable, then Visual studio generated Array collections instead List<>.

```
[DataContract]
public enum DocumentAttachmentSourceType
{
    [EnumMember]
    ServiceMission                              
}

[MessageContract]
public class DocumentUploadRequest : IDisposable
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public long NodeId { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader]
    public DocumentAttachmentSourceType? AttachmentSource { get; set; } //This works
    //public DocumentAttachmentSourceType  AttachmentSource { get; set; }   //This not works !!!!!!!

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public System.IO.Stream Stream { get; set; }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Stream != null)
        {
            Stream.Close();
            Stream = null;
        }
    } 

}
```