# WCF DataContract with custom List Attribute

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have a WCF webservice, that exposes these classes:

```
  [DataContract]
    public class TemplatesFormat
    {        
        List<DynAttribute> _dynsattributes = new List<DynAttribute>();

        [DataMember]
        public List<DynAttribute> DynsAttributes
        {
            get { return _dynsattributes; }
            set { _dynsattributes = value; }
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class DynAttribute
    {
        string _key = "";
        string _val = "";
        [DataMember]
        public string Key
        {
            get { return _key; }
            set { _key = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Value
        {
            get { return _val; }
            set { _val = value; }
        }
    }
```

Basically, 2 classes. DynAttribute with 2 string attributes and TemplatesFormat, with an attribute that is a List of DynAttribute class. 
So far, so good.

But, when I reference the web service from an ASP.NET web page and try to use the TemplatesFormat, I can't see the List attribute.

I mean, I actually "see" it, but it is not a list (does not contain an "Add()") and I don't know how to use it.

I think I am missing something related with de [DataContrat] and the fact that it is a custom type, since, I don't have the same problem with DynAttribute class (I see the Key and Value attributes because they are strings) but, I can't get it right for the List...

Any idea???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add reference to wcf service you need to change Collection Type to Generic List.
Please see my post [wcf-proxy-returning-array-instead-of-list-even-though-collection-type-generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513027/wcf-proxy-returning-array-instead-of-list-even-though-collection-type-generic/13959223#13959223) for more details and snipp picture.

Answer (score 1):

WCF is meant to support consumption by many other platforms.  Because `List<DynAttribute>` is not a primitive type, it is likely converting it to `DynAttribute[]`.

In your consuming application.  Try taking your variable and seeing if you can `.ToList()` it to turn it back into the `List<DynAttribute>` you're expecting.

Comment: And there is no way of telling it to serialize that List<DynAttribute> too?

Comment: @Jeffery Khan this is not true, you can have List<T> without any problem

Comment: Personally I prefer to leave them as arrays, but for what you're looking for, it looks like it is client-side you'll need to deserialize to `List<T>`.  Take a look at Gregor's answer below.